How to fix libpoppler-qt5-1 dependency on older package
I'm trying to install the packages krop and kile on my Ubuntu 22.04.04 (Jammy) system:

sudo apt-get install krop

I get the following error: packages have unmet dependencies

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libpoppler-qt5-1 : Depends: libpoppler118 (= 22.02.0-2ubuntu0.3) but 22.02.0-2ubuntu0.4 is to be installed

In other words, krop requires libpoppler-qt5-1, which in turn requires libpoppler118 version 22.02.0-2ubuntu0.3.
Running dpkg -l libpoppler118 gives:

libpoppler118:amd64 22.02.0-2ubuntu0.4

In other words, libpoppler118 is installed on my system, but it's a newer version than libpoppler-qt5-1 expects or requires. Unfortunately I cannot downgrade libpoppler118 to version 22.02.0-2ubuntu0.3 because my employer's software compliance system than determines that my system is out-of-date and forces me to upgrade.
I tried installing poppler-qt5-1 version 22.02.0-2ubuntu0.4 through this website: https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/jammy/universe/updates/libpoppler-qt5-1 but this gives me the same error that it depends on libpoppler118 (= 22.02.0-2ubuntu0.3)
Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

It seems that your system is trying to install an older version of libpoppler-qt5-1, than what is available on the repositories. You seem to have the version in the original jammy repositories, rather than the one in jammy-updates.
First, open Software Sources, and open the updates tab, and ensure that "Important Security Updates" and "Recommended Updates" are enabled.

Afterward, run the following commands to fully update the system
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade

Now run the following command to install krop.
sudo apt install krop

